# CustomAuthorize Attribute on WEBAPI asking credentials indefinitely

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a custom authorize attribute, which is very simple, for the sake of brevity of this question,

As you can see in method: HandleUnauthorizedRequest, I am returning a 401 if the user is not authorized.

However in the brower, IT keeps asking username and password indefinitely, if I change that 401 with another Response Code, then it shows correctly on the screen the Unauthorized message.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (Authorize(actionContext))
            {
                return;
            }else
            {
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            }

        }




        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {          
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)401,
                Content = new StringContent("No tiene autorización para realizar esta acción")
            };
        }

        private bool Authorize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
                //boolean logic to determine if you are authorized.  
                //We check for a valid token in the request header or cookie.

                if (user.Contains("luis"))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting.. Did you add  [AllowAnonymous] to your Login controller? and then skip authorization for this controller in OnAuthorization() function.

Comment: its webapi, so there is no login controller because its window integrated authentication